# How to use Data.Functor.Invariant?

Tags: haskell

Could someone please provide me an example of

```
invmap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> f a -> f b
```

and for what is Invariant good for?

Comment: Where did you see this function? I cannot find it in Hoogle.

Comment: The obvious example would be [`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo). But, is it really sensible to call this “invariant functor”?

Comment: here we go https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invariant-0.5/docs/Data-Functor-Invariant.html

Comment: @zero_coding have you tried reading the docs you're linking to? Seems like `invmap` is just `xmap` from the article.

Comment: @leftaroundabout please provide an example.

Answer (score 9):

Mostly, people *don't* use `Invariant`. The reason you'd want to is if you're working with a type in which a variable appears in both covariant and contravariant positions.

```
newtype Endo a = Endo {appEndo :: a -> a}
newtype Foo a = Foo (Maybe a -> IO a)
data Bar a = Bar [a] (a -> Bool)
```

None of these are instances of `Functor` or `Contravariant`, but they can all be instances of `Invariant`.

The reason people rarely bother is that if you need to do a lot of mapping over such a type, you're typically better off factoring it out into covariant and contravariant parts. Each invariant functor can be expressed in terms of a `Profunctor`:

```
newtype FooP x y = FooP (Maybe x -> IO y)
data BarP x y = Bar [y] (x -> Bool)
```

Now

```
Endo a ~= (->) a a
Foo a ~= FooP a a
Bar a ~= BarP a a
-- So we'd likely write newtype Bar a = Bar (BarP a a)
```

It's generally easier to see what's going on if you unwrap the `newtype`, `dimap` over the underlying `Profunctor`, and then wrap it up again rather than messing around with `invmap`.

---

How can we transform an `Invariant` functor into a `Profunctor`? First, let's dispose of sums and products. If we can turn `f` and `g` into profunctors `fp` and `gp`, then we can surely turn `f :+: g` and `f :*: g` into equivalent profunctor sums and products.

What about compositions? It's slightly trickier, but not much. Suppose that we can turn `f` and `g` into profunctors `fp` and `gp`. Now define

```
-- Compose f g a ~= ComposeP fp gp a a
newtype ComposeP p q a b = ComposeP (p (q b a) (q a b))
instance (Profunctor p, Profunctor q) => Profunctor (ComposeP p q) where
  dimap f g (ComposeP p) = ComposeP $ dimap (dimap g f) (dimap f g) p
```

Now suppose you have a function type; `f a -> g a`. This looks like `fp b a -> gp a b`.

I think that should cover most of the interesting cases.

Comment: “Each invariant functor can be expressed in terms of a `Profunctor`”\[Citation needed\]

Comment: @leftroundabout, does that need a citation? It's just generalizing the type of `invmap` to a two-argument data type and getting `dimap`.

Comment: @Carl, I suspect leftaroundabout means that I should support the claim that *every* `Invariant` instance can be split like that. I'm quite confident of that, but I don't have a citation or a proof. A related claim I also have no idea how to prove is that `Invariant` instances are unique. I will try to add some explanation of why it's true.